# Why is gmail rejecting my SMTP connection?

Tags: python, gmail, smtplib

I set my gmail account to allow "Less secure apps access" and I use server.starttls() in smtplib in python to make sure the session is encrypted so why is google still periodically rejecting my login with "Please log in via your web browser and then try again. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 "

```
server = smtplib.SMTP(GMAIL_SERVER, GMAIL_PORT)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(GMAIL_USER, GMAIL_PASS)
server.sendmail(GMAIL_USER, [to_address], mime_msg.as_string())
server.close()
logger.info("Email successfully sent")
```

Comment: Please post your code, and the full error message.

Comment: It is their strange way to be unattractive as a mail server for automated tools.

Comment: Google wants you to use their API in preference to smtp and Google is big enough to make that stick.

Comment: @BoarGules Unless you work for Google i dont think you can state what google does or does not want us to use.  IMO Google wants developers to use the best tool for their their user case.  This may be the SMTP server or the Gmail API is up to the developer.  If they didn't want us using the SMTP server they would block it instead of enabling serval ways for us to login to it securely.   (XOAUTH2, Less secure appts, and app passwords)

Comment: @geronimo please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: @DalmTo That is what their documentation says. I'm not making it up.

Comment: I added the code, thanks  @boargules There's a way to send mail in python using google's api rather than smtp?

Answer (score 0):

When using the Gmail SMTP from a programming a lot of times you will get an error with it rejecting your login.  It wants you to use the browser using Xoauth2.

A alternative would be to try and use an [apps password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) infested of your true password.  In my experience this tends to fix the issue, its often the case when the user has 2fa enabled.

Comment: Thanks. I have 2FA disabled though.  I guess maybe I should just find another free email provider to use with my automated script.  Any recommendations?